# How to properly deal with callbacks with jQuery and Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, callback

I have the following situation:

A jQuery `$.get` calling a local node.js service:

```
function getUser() {
    var name = $('#inputName').val();
    var url = "/users/" + name;

    $.get(url, function(err, res) {
        alert('Local service done');
    })
        .done(function() {
            alert('Remote service done');
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert('Error')
        });
    }
```

A local node.js service calling a remote service:

```
router.get('/users/:name', function (req, res){
    //code
    var userId = endpoints.findUserId(req.params.name); 
    res.send(userId);
});
```

The requests always passes through the first alert before the remote service call finishes, and never triggers the `.done` neither the `.fail` functions.

How can I know when the remote service request has finished and the best way to deal with its response?

Comment: That's impossible, there's no way the callback used in `$.get` alerts **before** the call is done, and that neither `done` nor `fail` executes.

Comment: I mean, it alerts before the request is finished.

Comment: `var userId = endpoints.findUserId(req.params.name);` with no callback followed by `res.send(userId);` looks fishy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use Jquery Promises for this:

```
$.when($.get(...))
.then(function(value) {
    console.log('success!')
}, function(error) {
    console.log('rejection');
});
```

**The Promise Contract**

There is one Resolution or Rejection
A promise is resolved one time. It will never be fulfilled if it has been rejected or rejected if it has been fulfilled.

**Listeners are executed one time**

An individual callback or errback will be executed once and only once. This follows from the first rule of the contract.

**Promises remember their state**

A promise that is resolved with a value remembers the fulfillment. If a callback is attached in the future to this promise, it will be executed with the previously resolved value. The same is true of errbacks. If a promise is rejected and an errback is attached after the rejection, it will be executed with the rejected value. Promises behave the same way regardless of whether they are already resolved or resolved in the future.